# Create swagger.yaml file in the project root folder for NestJS application

Tags: gitlab, swagger, nestjs

I'm using NestJS to create a BE application and I enabled the swagger using the swagger module using below syntax

```
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);  
SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
```

My question is about is there is a way to convert/save the document as .yaml file in the root folder? So that any members on GitLab repo can view application's APIs and DTOs without running the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using `json-to-pretty-yaml` package so now I can convert the document to string yaml using `YAML.stringify(document)` then save the output to .yaml file.

```
    import * as fs from 'fs';
    import * as YAML from 'json-to-pretty-yaml';
    ....
    ....
      const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
      SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
    
      const data = YAML.stringify(document);
      fs.writeFile("swagger.yaml", data, (err) => {
        if (err)
          console.log(err);
        else {
          console.log("swagger.yaml file has been updated successfully\n");
        }
      });
```